# derivative formula related to Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction

Tags: continued-fractions

[What is the derivative of Rogers-Ramanujan Continued Fraction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2111679/what-is-the-derivative-of-rogers-ramanujan-continued-fraction)

In the answer of upper link, Nikos Bagis claimed that
$$ R'(q)=5^{-1}q^{-5/6}f(-q)^4R(q)\sqrt[6]{R(q)^{-5}-11-R(q)^5}\textrm{, }:(d1)$$

Where can I get a proof for this formula?

Comment: A proof is given in Berndt, _Ramanujan's Notebooks_, Part III, page 267, equation (11.6). See also Andrews and Berndt, _Ramanujan's Lost Notebook_, Part I, page 334,

Comment: The radical on right is same as $q^{-1/6}f(-q)/f(-q^5)$ so that the derivative is equal to $f^{5}(-q)R(q)/5qf(-q^5)$ and thus it is sufficient to prove that $(\log R(q)) '=f^{5}(-q)/5qf(-q^5)$.